# Tools to manage SQL Server and Oracle database from the desktop

Tags: sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2008 and Oracle 11G on my system.

Running both database services is making my system very slow. In order to stop the services I have to go to Services and stop them manually.

Is there way to manage the services from my desktop, similar to XAMPP?

Answer (score 3):

You could create a couple of batch files on your desktop and use `net start` and `net stop`.  Then you'd just double-click on whatever action you want to take.  No software required.

`net start MSSQLSERVER`
`net stop MSSLQSERVER`

Or, you could create Powershell scripts and use `start-service` and `stop-service`

`start-service MSSQLSERVER`
`stop-service MSSQLSERVER`